# Python: Lambda return string if char is digit

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am working on a dataframe. I used pd.read_csv to read a file.
I have a column in which is an ID. Some contains alphabet chars and some are purely numeric. Because of this, the numeric data where read as numbers. I want to transform them to string so later I can df.replace them with real names.

```
staff_df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Name': 'Kelly', 'ID': 'ABC321'},
    {'Name': 'Sally', 'ID': 'XYZ123'},
    {'Name': 'James', 'ID': '123450'}
])

staff_df = staff_df.set_index('Name')
```

This is my code right now, but is invalid syntax:

```
staff_df[1] = staff_df[1].apply(lambda x: str(x) if x.isdigit())
```

It will be good if its lambda. :)

Comment: You don't need no lambdas... `staff_df['ID'] = staff_df['ID'].astype(str)`

Comment: Do you need `df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype={'ID':str})` ?

Comment: `staff_df.loc["James", "ID"]` is a string.  Which numeric data are getting read as numbers?

Comment: Ok shit. My problem is when it is copied to CSV. It converts numbers with some raise to 10. E.g. 3223E+10

Comment: What do you mean by 'when it is copied to CSV'? Are you opening the CSV outside pandas? Maybe in Excel?

Comment: @Nikko - sounds like you're copying data to Excel. It often performs automatic conversion of big numbers to scientific format. If that is the case try formatting the cells as numbers before pasting data. The problem is on excel side not pandas.

Comment: @MJB the numbers are really big. It automatically converts to scientific which makes more pain because it would include 3.222E+10. Then the string would be "3.222E+10" when converted in pandas. Any help?

Comment: @MJB, when converted to numbers, some digits are rounded off. :(

Comment: @Nikko, are you opening the file in Excel at some point? If so, the solution is probably "don't open the csv in Excel", pandas knows the ID is a string column, so won't be doing any rounding.

Comment: @Nikko you may use `float_precision` , `float_format` when reading csv in dataframe and writing to csv respectively. make required changes in your question.

Comment: @Nikko - so I understand you are dumping data into excel at some point. Could you edit your question to show exactly what you're doing, including the part where you move data to excel.